# 301 Redirect with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^category?$
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ http://domain.com/$3/ [L,R=permanent]
```

Currently I have the following redirection and it is working like a charm. Now I want to make sure that the link does not begins with /category/ therefore I have inserted the condition. Unfortunately it does not seems to work. Please help. Thanks.

Another question is, how to make that the end permalink that is between the slash is selected to be redirected only. For example, I may have links like http://domain.com/downloads/26-fine-wallpapers/ and http://domain.com/downloads/icons/35-nice-icons/ and I want links like these to be redirected to http://newdomain.com/35-nice-icons/ and http://newdomain.com/26-fine-wallpapers/

I am using wordpress actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description you only have two path segments. So your pattern should be:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/$3/ [L,R=permanent]
```

And to exclude `/category/…`, you can either check the request URI path in *REQUEST_URI*:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/$3/ [L,R=permanent]
```

Or you check the matched value of the first group:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=category
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/$3/ [L,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a prefixing `/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category?$
```

Comment: @Gan try removing the `?` and possibly the `$`: `!^/category/`